# Можно ли выводить определенный контент проверяя разрешение дисплея?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Добрый день.

Недавно купил шаблон на themeforest он собака тяжелый до ужаса, главная страница при загрузке выдает около 500 запросов к бд, попытаюсь объяснить что там к чему и что я хочу сделать.

Значит главная работает с visual composer, в нем созданы кастомные модули, те я открыл главную добавил ряд потом колонку и туда воткнул модуль с нужной категорией, но есть одно но, для десктопа меня все утраивает, но для мобильной версии вывод этой категории мне абсолютно не подходит как с визуальной стороны так и с логической, визуал я бы сделал медиа запросами подогнал бы, но логику нет.

Я бы мог воткнуть еще один модуль с уже готовой мне логикой и стилями, скрыть его для дестопа а для мобильной версии ставить в display block, но если я так сделаю я по умолчанию еще больше буду нагружать главную страницу так как модуль будет грузиться не один а два, собственно вопрос: Можно ли как-то проверять разрешение экрана и если оно меньше чем допустим 600 пикселей подгружать новый модуль, вероятно ка-то можно отдавать мобильному пользователю другую главную страницу с другой логикой.

Answer (score 3):

Тут как вариант можно использовать функцию [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) для определения мобильных устройств и загружать нужный блок для них.
Например так

```
function mobile_home_redirect(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
         include( get_template_directory() . '/home-mobile.php' );
         exit;
   }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mobile_home_redirect' );
```

Comment: Хм интерестно, подставил шаблон, другой страницы что бы проверить и почему-то вывел мне полотно компоузера, шапка и футер подключились хорошо а вот то что в цикле if have posts white have posts не вывелось, точнее ввелись шорткоды. Вероятно знаете в чем дело.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/205v6sz/9

Comment: Ну в общем это не выход. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188881/proper-usage-of-wp-is-mobile/188897#188897

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use it in your theme. It's used in WP core on administration side for adding touch scripts, mobile button etc. It's very dumb, it just detects User Agent string which can anybody change. And the biggest why not to use it is that you can have a trouble if you use it with a cache plugin because it can show mobile version when desktop version should showed.. It's safe to use it in backend because all caching plugins caching only frontend not backend.
I think that the safest method would be input all content and show/hide whatever you want via media queries.

Comment: Как вариант, но данная функция проверяет наличие в $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] словосочетаний: Mobile, Android, Silk/, Kindle, BlackBerry, Opera Mini, Opera Mobi. Что может привести не к ожидаемым результатам. Я все же бы отправлял первым JS скрипт который пробегался бы по объектам navigator и window. На основе чего отправлял аяксом некую переменную, далее серверная часть уже ориентируясь на нее строила шаблон страницы.Можно еще и куку повесить, но это уже другая история.